# unable to correctly iterate over text inputs in table row

Tags: jquery

I have a page that allows the user to dynamically add table rows when the user clicks an "Add Participant" button. The button id is "btnParticipant".  When the button is clicked I'm calling a custom function assigned to the variable "myTest".

I'm trying to find all tr elements in the table with the id "participantTable" and then find the elements of type text and for each of the text inputs I find I want to check to see if the value of the text input is not empty.  If it is, then I want to go to the next element, which should be an `<a>` tag and from there find the first `<img>` element and hide it.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    var myTest=function() {
        j$('[id$=participantTable] tr.dataRow input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if (j$(this).val() != '') {
                j$(this).next().find('img').hide();
            }
        });         
    }
    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$('[id$=btnParticipant]').click(j$.myTest);
    }); 
</script>
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the images are not getting hidden. I'm pretty new to jquery so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you should not use same ID for more than one element in a page

Comment: He's using the `$=` operator which means `ends with`. However, you could get a LOT more help if you created a jsFiddle or, at the very least, showed your HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
var tblTexts = j$('table#participantTable').find(':text');
j$.each(tblTexts, function(i, v) {
    if (j$(this).val() != "") {
        j$(this).next('a').find('img').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  My apologies for not including the code or a js fiddle.  The reason I didn't is because the page code is rendered in Salesforce and it is a mass of code to display.  Also, trying to extract out the raw html to create an example in js fiddle might not render the same results.  I've edited my original post and tried to paste in the relevant code source, but it might not be helpful and is a mess.  I tried your example and still am not getting the images to hide.

Comment: You could slice out the RELEVANT portions of the markup to post. Just do a `View Source` with your browser and copy/paste the parts that deal with `participantTable`.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but I grabbed all the raw html from page source and copied into js fiddle.  It is a mess of code.  If it is too much of a mess to decipher, no worries. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Dman100/KehmH/1/)

Comment: So, you're trying to use this small bit of code on this massively complex website that you didn't even develop? I'm out. Good luck!